# Is there a way to register a search result callback when using Google CSE v2?

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

In version one (v1) of Google's Custom Search Engine code, there was a method called `.setSearchCompleteCallback` which would allow you to call some Javascript when the search results had returned. The documentation for that code can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-reference).

The search engine object has been moved from `google.search.CustomSearchControl` in v1 to `google.search.cse.element` in v2.

The [current version (v2)](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#cse-element) doesn't seem to have the `.setSearchCompleteCallback` method, and I can't see a way to register a callback for when the search results are finished. I have experimented to varying degrees of success with Jquery's ajaxStart and ajaxEnd methods, but I wondered if there was an "official" way to do this built into the Google CSE code.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that there _is_ a callback parameter but that it is attached to the `window.__gcse` object and it seems only to be called upon the CSE initialization.

Comment: Have you tried giving the element a gname attribute, then accessing your specific custom search element via google.search.cse.element.getElement(gname)?  The google.search.cse.element object doesn't refer to your actual element, but it provides utility functions, including that one to access your element.  See here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#cse-element

(I haven't tried this myself, so I'm not certain whether the returned element will have the original v1 methods, but I'm interested to know!

Comment: Just checked myself, and the answer is no.  The search element has only four methods: clearAllResults, execute, getInputQuery, and preFillQuery.  It looks like V2 is intended to be a simplified, easy to implement version, but without most of the power of V1.

Answer (score 2):

Not elegant, but the only thing I could find.

I know people are going to comment about using an interval that never ends, but until a better solution is found this is what we have.

```
setInterval(function () {
    var resultInfo = $('.gsc-result:first');
    if (resultInfo.length && !resultInfo.data('isOld')) {
        resultInfo.data('isOld', true);

        console.log('new results');
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: No-jQuery solution: `setInterval(function () { var resultInfo = document.querySelector('.gsc-result'); if (resultInfo && !resultInfo.isOld) {  resultInfo.isOld = true; console.log('new results'); }}, 500);`

Answer (score 0):

You can determine that search results have changed by watching the results HTML code using MutationObserver.

```
// Where to put search results
var resultsElement = document.getElementById('results');

// Creating results box
window.google.search.cse.element.render({
    div: resultsElement,
    tag: 'searchresults-only',
    attributes: {
        overlayResults: false
    }
});

// Watching the "new results" event
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mutations.length; ++i) {
        if (mutations[i].target.classList.contains('gsc-results')) {
            console.log('Search complete!');
            break;
        }
    }
}).observe(resultsElement, {
    subtree:       true,
    attributes:    false,
    childList:     true,
    characterData: false
});
```

It works as good as the V1's search complete callback. Old browsers don't support `MutationObserver` but you can use [a polyfill](https://github.com/megawac/MutationObserver.js) to enable it.